# Struts 2.5 + convention plugin and slashes in action

Tags: java, struts2, struts2-convention-plugin, wildcard-mapping

I'm developing a Struts2 web-app with [Struts2 convention plugin](https://struts.apache.org/docs/convention-plugin.html) and I want to enable the wildcards mapping in order to do somenthing like:

```
http://localhost:8080/myApp/user            -> go to users' list
http://localhost:8080/myApp/user/1          -> go to user 1 detail page
http://localhost:8080/myApp/user/create     -> go to users' create form
http://localhost:8080/myApp/user/1/edit     -> go to user 1 edit page
```

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6037820/is-it-possible-to-use-wildcard-method-invocation-in-struts2-with-conventions-plu/9592576#9592576) I've created a Struts2 Controller with annotations and a wildcard called `{action}`:

```
public class MyController extends ActionSupport {

   [...]

   @Override
   @Action(value = "controller/{action}", results = {
      @Result(name = SUCCESS, location = "/controller.jsp")
      @Result(name = INPUT, location = "/create.jsp")
   })
   public String execute(){ return SUCCESS }

   [...]
}
```

But when I try to open the url `http://localhost:8080/myApp/controller/1` or `http://localhost:8080/myApp/controller/create` the browser returns a `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS` error.

Anyone knows what am I doing wrong?

Here is my struts2.properties file, if you need more informations let me know:

```
### Struts default properties
###(can be overridden by a struts.properties file in the root of the classpath)
###

### This can be used to set your default locale and encoding scheme
# struts.locale=en_US
struts.i18n.encoding=UTF-8

### if specified, the default object factory can be overridden here
### Note: short-hand notation is supported in some cases, such as "spring"
###       Alternatively, you can provide a com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory subclass name here
# struts.objectFactory=spring

### specifies the autoWiring logic when using the SpringObjectFactory.
### valid values are: name, type, auto, and constructor (name is the default)
struts.objectFactory.spring.autoWire=name

### indicates to the struts-spring integration if Class instances should be cached
### this should, until a future Spring release makes it possible, be left as true
### unless you know exactly what you are doing!
### valid values are: true, false (true is the default)
struts.objectFactory.spring.useClassCache=true

### ensures the autowire strategy is always respected.
### valid values are: true, false (false is the default)
struts.objectFactory.spring.autoWire.alwaysRespect=false

### By default SpringObjectFactory doesn't support AOP
### This flag was added just temporally to check if nothing is broken
### See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WW-4110
struts.objectFactory.spring.enableAopSupport=false

### if specified, the default object type determiner can be overridden here
### Note: short-hand notation is supported in some cases, such as "tiger" or "notiger"
###       Alternatively, you can provide a com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.ObjectTypeDeterminer implementation name here
### Note: By default, com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.DefaultObjectTypeDeterminer is used which handles type detection
###       using generics. com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.GenericsObjectTypeDeterminer was deprecated since XWork 2, it's
###       functions are integrated in DefaultObjectTypeDeterminer now.
###       To disable tiger support use the "notiger" property value here.
#struts.objectTypeDeterminer=tiger
#struts.objectTypeDeterminer=notiger

### Parser to handle HTTP POST requests, encoded using the MIME-type multipart/form-data
# struts.multipart.parser=cos
# struts.multipart.parser=pell
# struts.multipart.parser=jakarta-stream
struts.multipart.parser=jakarta
# uses javax.servlet.context.tempdir by default
struts.multipart.saveDir=
struts.multipart.maxSize=2097152

### Load custom property files (does not override struts.properties!)
# struts.custom.properties=application,org/apache/struts2/extension/custom

### How request URLs are mapped to and from actions
#struts.mapper.class=org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.mapper.DefaultActionMapper

### Used by the DefaultActionMapper
### You may provide a comma separated list, e.g. struts.action.extension=action,jnlp,do
### The blank extension allows you to match directory listings as well as pure action names
### without interfering with static resources, which can be specified as an empty string
### prior to a comma e.g. struts.action.extension=, or struts.action.extension=x,y,z,,
struts.action.extension=,

### Used by FilterDispatcher
### If true then Struts serves static content from inside its jar.
### If false then the static content must be available at <context_path>/struts
struts.serve.static=true

### Used by FilterDispatcher
### This is good for development where one wants changes to the static content be
### fetch on each request.
### NOTE: This will only have effect if struts.serve.static=true
### If true -> Struts will write out header for static contents such that they will
###             be cached by web browsers (using Date, Cache-Content, Pragma, Expires)
###             headers).
### If false -> Struts will write out header for static contents such that they are
###            NOT to be cached by web browser (using Cache-Content, Pragma, Expires
###            headers)
struts.serve.static.browserCache=true

### Set this to false if you wish to disable implicit dynamic method invocation
### via the URL request. This includes URLs like foo!bar.action, as well as params
### like method:bar (but not action:foo).
### An alternative to implicit dynamic method invocation is to use wildcard
### mappings, such as <action name="*/*" method="{2}" class="actions.{1}">
struts.enable.DynamicMethodInvocation=false

### Set this to true if you wish to allow slashes in your action names.  If false,
### Actions names cannot have slashes, and will be accessible via any directory
### prefix.  This is the traditional behavior expected of WebWork applications.
### Setting to true is useful when you want to use wildcards and store values
### in the URL, to be extracted by wildcard patterns, such as
### <action name="*/*" method="{2}" class="actions.{1}"> to match "/foo/edit" or
### "/foo/save".
struts.enable.SlashesInActionNames=true

### Disables support for action: prefix
struts.mapper.action.prefix.enabled=false

### Blocks access to actions in other namespace than current with action: prefix
struts.mapper.action.prefix.crossNamespaces=false

### use alternative syntax that requires %{} in most places
### to evaluate expressions for String attributes for tags
struts.tag.altSyntax=true

### when set to true, Struts will act much more friendly for developers. This
### includes:
### - struts.i18n.reload=true
### - struts.configuration.xml.reload=true
### - raising various debug or ignorable problems to errors
###   For example: normally a request to foo.action?someUnknownField=true should
###                be ignored (given that any value can come from the web and it
###                should not be trusted). However, during development, it may be
###                useful to know when these errors are happening and be told of
###                them right away.
struts.devMode=true

### when set to true, resource bundles will be reloaded on _every_ request.
### this is good during development, but should never be used in production
### struts.i18n.reload=false

### Pattern matcher
struts.patternMatcher=regex

### Standard UI theme
### Change this to reflect which path should be used for JSP control tag templates by default
struts.ui.theme=xhtml
struts.ui.templateDir=template
### Change this to use a different token to indicate template theme expansion
struts.ui.theme.expansion.token=~~~
#sets the default template type. Either ftl, vm, or jsp
struts.ui.templateSuffix=ftl

### Configuration reloading
### This will cause the configuration to reload struts.xml when it is changed
### struts.configuration.xml.reload=false

### Location of velocity.properties file.  defaults to velocity.properties
struts.velocity.configfile=velocity.properties

### Comma separated list of VelocityContext classnames to chain to the StrutsVelocityContext
struts.velocity.contexts =

### Location of the velocity toolbox
struts.velocity.toolboxlocation=

### used to build URLs, such as the UrlTag
struts.url.http.port=80
struts.url.https.port=443
### possible values are: none, get or all
struts.url.includeParams=none

### Load custom default resource bundles
# struts.custom.i18n.resources=testmessages,testmessages2

### workaround for some app servers that don't handle HttpServletRequest.getParameterMap()
### often used for WebLogic, Orion, and OC4J
struts.dispatcher.parametersWorkaround=false

### configure the Freemarker Manager class to be used
### Allows user to plug-in customised Freemarker Manager if necessary
### MUST extends off org.apache.struts2.views.freemarker.FreemarkerManager
#struts.freemarker.manager.classname=org.apache.struts2.views.freemarker.FreemarkerManager

### Enables caching of FreeMarker templates
### Has the same effect as copying the templates under WEB_APP/templates
### struts.freemarker.templatesCache=false

### Enables caching of models on the BeanWrapper
struts.freemarker.beanwrapperCache=false

### See the StrutsBeanWrapper javadocs for more information
struts.freemarker.wrapper.altMap=true

### maxStrongSize for MruCacheStorage for freemarker, when set to 0 SoftCacheStorage which performs better in heavy loaded application
### check WW-3766 for more details
struts.freemarker.mru.max.strong.size=0

### configure the XSLTResult class to use stylesheet caching.
### Set to true for developers and false for production.
struts.xslt.nocache=false

### Whether to always select the namespace to be everything before the last slash or not
struts.mapper.alwaysSelectFullNamespace=false

### Whether to allow static method access in OGNL expressions or not
struts.ognl.allowStaticMethodAccess=false

### Whether to throw a RuntimeException when a property is not found
### in an expression, or when the expression evaluation fails
struts.el.throwExceptionOnFailure=false

### Logs as Warnings properties that are not found (very verbose)
struts.ognl.logMissingProperties=false

### Caches parsed OGNL expressions, but can lead to memory leaks
### if the application generates a lot of different expressions
struts.ognl.enableExpressionCache=true

### Indicates if Dispatcher should handle unexpected exceptions by calling sendError()
### or simply rethrow it as a ServletException to allow future processing by other frameworks like Spring Security
struts.handle.exception=true

### Struts Convention plugin

### Directory where templates are located
struts.convention.result.path=/WEB-INF/views

### Suffix used to find actions based on class names
struts.convention.action.suffix=Controller

### Create action mappings, even if no @Action is found
struts.convention.action.mapAllMatches=true

### Packages whose name end with one of these strings will be scanned for actions
struts.convention.package.locators=controller
```

**EDIT**

The action Index is called with the app base url, `http://localhost:8080/myApp` and redirects to `http://localhost:8080/myApp/myController` (and it works). The problem comes out when I try to reach `http://localhost:8080/myApp/myController/whatever`

Here is the Index class code:

```
@Results({
    @Result(name = SUCCESS, location = "${redirectName}", type = "redirectAction")
})
public class Index extends ActionSupport {

    private static final Logger LOG = LogManager.getLogger(Index.class);

    private String redirectName;

    public String getRedirectName() {
        return redirectName;
    }

    @Override
    public String execute() {
        redirectName = "myController";
        return SUCCESS;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is not working?

Comment: As I wrote: "when I try to open the url http://localhost:8080/myApp/controller/1 or http://localhost:8080/myApp/controller/create the browser returns a ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS error."

Comment: I don't see any redirects in your code.

Comment: Me neither... Maybe should I change something in tomcat's configuration?

Comment: @RomanC I was forgetting about the index route (I mean the localhost:8080/myApp/controller). This one returns the correct result...

Comment: Do you have an index page that redirects?

Comment: No sir, I have a Index controller... I will add the code to the question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116204/discussion-between-ilgala-and-roman-c).

Comment: Does it work if you define `"controller/{action}/"` and call `localhost:8080/myApp/controller/1/` ?

Comment: Do you have `error-page` in your web.xml? And is any error happening in your action?

Comment: @IlGala You are reinventing a wheel, use REST controller.